# Given a collection $C$ of sets, prove that there is $X\in C$ of minimal cardinality.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

While reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435722/x-mathscr-t-is-compact-iff-every-infinite-subset-of-x-has-a-complete-l), I noticed that at one point in the answer it was assumed that given a collection $C$ of sets, there is some $X\in C$ of minimal cardinality. I couldn't find a proof online nor come up with one myself.

I was wondering how the result could be shown, and if ordinals -which I know not a lot about- need to be involved.

Comment: Any sey of cardinals has a minimal element, because cardinals are well ordered

Comment: One often does this by identifying cardinals with $\aleph_\alpha$ for $\alpha$ an ordinal, and then using well-order of ordinals. But here is a different proof that does not look to explicitly use ordinals: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1954-005-02/S0002-9939-1954-0060558-3/S0002-9939-1954-0060558-3.pdf

Comment: BTW not finding proofs online might mean that you were using the wrong search terms. If you search "cardinals well ordered" you should get lots of hits.

Comment: Learn about ordinals. It's like asking about the existence of nowhere differentiable functions without the Baire Category Theorem: yes, it's doable, but it's much easier to learn about a new concept and apply it here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila . Let $Y\le X$ iff there is an injection $f:Y\to X.$  Let $Y\approx X$ iff there is a bijection $g:Y\to X.$ Can we prove in ZF that if $C\ne \phi$ then $\exists X\in C\;\forall Y\in C\,(Y\le X\implies Y\approx X)\;$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: No, you can embed every partial order into the cardinals. My first paper showed that you can have a model where every ordinal embeds on reverse into the cardinals, and DC holds up to any prescribed degree.