# Infinite subset of compact space has an accumulation point

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

Let $(K,\tau)$ be a compact space and $B$ be an infinite subset of $E$. Why can we conclude that $B$ has a $\tau$-accumulation point$^1$?

We may assume the contrary so that for every $x\in B$, there is a neighborhood $\Omega_x\in\tau$ of $x$ with $B\cap\Omega_x\setminus\{x\}\ne\emptyset$. If $F\subseteq B$ is finite, then $$\left|B\cap\bigcup_{x\in F}\Omega_x\right|\le|F|\in\mathbb N,\tag1$$ but since $B$ is infinite, this simplies $$B\not\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in F}\Omega_x\tag2.$$ In particular, $$K\not\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in F}\Omega_x\tag3.$$

> However, I'm not able to conclude that this is a contradiction to the compactness of $(K,\tau)$. It is clearly a contradiction to the assertion that $(B,\left.\tau\right|_B)$, where $\left.\tau\right|_B:=\{\Omega\cap B:\Omega\in\tau\}$, is compact. But unless we assume that $B$ is $\tau$-closed, $(B,\left.\tau\right|_B)$ doesn't need to be compact.
>
> What am I missing?

---

$^1$ $x\in E$ is called $\tau$-accumulation point of $B$ if for every $\tau$-neighborhood $N$ of $x$ it holds $B\cap N\setminus\{x\}\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: @KReiser So, I need to enrich $(\Omega_x)_{x\in B}$ by some further open neighborhoods $\Omega_x$ for $x\in E\setminus B$?

Comment: No, you need not do this - remember, accumulation points can be in $K$, not $E$, so applying the definition, every point in $K$ has a neighborhood which intersects $E$ in at most one point. This gives an open cover of $K$ with no finite refinement, contradicting compactness.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry, you're right, as Brian M. Scott pointed out below, I've messed up the definition of an accumulation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re missing is that an accumulation point of $B$ need not be **in** $B$. If $B$ has none, then each $x\in K$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $U_x\cap B\subseteq\{x\}$. $\{U_x:x\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$, so there is a finite $F\subseteq K$ such that $K=\bigcup_{x\in F}U_x$. Each $U_x$ contains at most one point of $B$, and $B\subseteq K$, so $B$ must be finite.

You could also work in $\operatorname{cl}B$, which is compact and must contain any accumulation points of $B$, but it’s simpler just to work in $K$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really messed up the definition. Does the converse hold as well (at least in metric spaces)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: You’re welcome. You mean, if every infinite subset of a metric space has an accumulation point, is the space compact? Yes; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point_compact) for more information.

Comment: Hm, what am I missing? According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/435722/47771) compactness of a general topological space is equivalent to the assertion that every infinite subset has an accumulation point. Why is compact then not equivalent to "limit point compactness"?

Comment: I think the answer to that question is wrong, isn't it? The constructed set might fail to be infinite.

Comment: @0xbadf00d note that there we use “complete accumulation point” which is stronger than a standard accumulation point as the OP uses.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ah, okay, just to be sure that I got you right. We can always show that an infinite subset of a compact space has a complete accumulation point (and hence an accumulation point). But in the other direction we necessarily need to assume that every infinite subset has a *complete* accumulation point in order to conclude compactness; unless the topology is metrizable (in which case it is sufficient to assume that every infinite subset has an accumulation point in order to conclude compactness). Right?

Comment: @If so, it's still not clear to me why we know that the set constructed in that post is necessarily infinite.

Comment: @0xbadf00d right. For metric spaces limit point compact implies compactness. The complete accumulation point characterisation was used by Tychonoff to prove that the product of compact spaces is compact. It’s due Aleksandrov and Urysohn IIRC.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: The set $A$ constructed in the answer has the same cardinality as $\mathcal{O}$, which is infinite.